# How to disable files to load from an external URL?

Tags: .htaccess, file, url, external

I have a website that have some files that are accessed publicly. Anyone can download them.

I have discovered lately that a website has added links to these files. With this way they claim ownership of them and they consume my bandwidth since they fetch them from my server.

How can i block other websites to refer to my website files?

I don't care if this files are not crawled by Google since now i refer to them using the rel="nofollow"

Can anyone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is preventing deeplinking of contents on your website. Try the following in appache httpd.conf file it will creates a failed request when hot linking of the specified file types occurs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|css|<whatever extensions you want to block>)$ - [F]
```

If the content you want to block is generated dynamically using some programming language, you can check if the referrer header matches your domain and then continue the processing of the request.

JAVA

```
"http://www.example.com".equals(request.getHeader("referer"));
```

PHP

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="http://www.example.com"
```